# Avoid assigning null to a val in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How could I avoid assigning null to userList in this code and get the same behaviour? Is it a bad practice?

```
fun update(type: Update) {
    fun List<UserList>.filter(listType: ListType): UserList? = this.firstOrNull { userList -> userList.listType == listType }

    val userList = if (model.list.isEmpty()) null else type.list.filter(getTabSelectedListType())
    val listToShow = userList?.toShoppingWrapper(model.cart)?.also {
        adapterShopping.update(it, type.updateCurrentList)
    }
    if (!listToShow.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        with(binding) {
          recyclerView.visible()
          emptyLayoutMyProducts.emptyView.gone()
          emptyLayoutFavorites.emptyView.gone()
          emptyLayoutLists.emptyView.gone()
        }
    } else when (binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(binding.tabLayout.selectedTabPosition)?.tag) {
        PRODUCTS -> showMyProductsEmptyLayout()
        FAVORITES -> showFavoritesEmptyLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: An empty list would be a good way.

Comment: There's no performance penalty for using `emptyList()`, since Kotlin uses a singleton object to represent all empty read-only lists of any type. But what's the point? You'll have to make the next lines more complicated in order to accommodate it.

Comment: I was just wondering if it's a bad practice doing it this way. I prefer it, because it simplifies the code, but not sure if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: The best way is whatever results in the clearest code, unless there is a performance bottleneck that needs to be optimized.